# Error unauthorized: authentication required while installing the Devbox in docker

Tags: magento2, installation

I am trying to install magento DevBox in docker, I followed all of the instructions and prerequisites, after configuring and downloading the package, i checked the MAGENTO_PUBLIC_KEY and MAGENTO_PRIVATE_KEY in the docker-compose.yml and they all right,
when I start the installation process via CLI it continue downloading till around 24% and then it produce the following error message:

ERROR: unauthorized: authentication required[image]
ERROR: No container found for web_1
Install Magento
ERROR: No container found for web_1
Press any key to continue . . .

Appreciate you kind advice,

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but your should check your key again(public,private) maybe it contain space. Try to install magento on directory non-C such as D: drive

Answer (score 0):

You need login account docker hub before init devbox by command:

```
$ docker login
```

Enter your username & Password for login then you can try init devbox.